# CSGO, Demofile, NodeJS Getting "cannot remove non-existent entity" error

Tags: node.js

I've recently been trying to use the Demo Parser for reading CSGO *.dem files.  It shouldn't be too difficult but for some reason it doesn't like it when I try to read the file.  I keep getting the same error:  "cannot remove non-existent entity".

Anyone else run into this issue?

I'm using the NodeJS code here: https://github.com/Brammz/csgo-demofile-parser and a sample of a *.dem file can be accessed here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk3tcy03tz5w254/test.dem?dl=0